# Is there a way to prevent a commit to a file in a remote repository?

Tags: git, githooks

I have some files (i.e some version files) in a remote repository that shouldn't be changed by future commits. Is there a way to make sure that future users who commit to this file will not be able to override the file in the remote, but still be able to push. Is there an easier way to do this than using githooks? I don't want to create a commit that undo's a users change in a githook. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: How thing may be done more easier than it is? Hooks technic exists especialy for purpose like this. Write a hook that check files and return error if something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you need based on your need is (I maybe wrong here) is to:-

> To temporarily ignore changes in a certain file: run
>
> ```
> git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
> ```
>
> Then when you want to track changes again:
>
> ```
> git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
> ```

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

This will retain the file in your git repo. Any local changes made in that file will not be able to be added, committed and pushed to the remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an additional commit undoing the user's changes if you use a `pre-receive` hook. This hook allows you to inspect the changes that are being pushed to your repo, and reject them (all or nothing) if they make changes to the forbidden file(s). Or if you'd prefer to just skip the changes to that file and allow their other changes to be pushed, use an `update` hook to reject only the changes to the forbidden files, while allowing the others through. (But this breaks the transactional integrity of their push, so you're making the assumption that the other changes will not depend on the changes they were attempting to make to the forbidden files.)

Comment: Is there a way to execute update hook on a merge (i.e when a pull request happens) ?

Comment: No. `update` is for when a push is received. If these files are being changed during a pull, that's trickier, as `pre-commit` doesn't get called then. There's `post-merge`, but that's called after completion of a merge, so all you could do then would be to revert the changes to the forbidden files.

Comment: I think you are confusing server side hooks and client hooks.